# Как в google spreadsheets подсчитать количество строк за определенный месяц?

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Для примера создал табличку (доступ только на комментирование, чтобы не было желания поудалять все у недобросовестных граждан) - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k9cW9Rc-ugZBw2guoJbcZFTzlZ8ICwQnnJDVXV3CCOk/edit?usp=sharing

Слева идет список сделанных "задач" пользователей по датам, есть в отдельной ячейки года и справа идет список пользователей и порядковые номера месяцев. Помогите пожалуйста написать формулу (справа, где месяцы), которая бы считала количество сделанных задач (из левого списка с пометкой "Сделано") по каждому пользователю, т.е. просто подсчет количества строк за определенный месяц/год пользователя с пометкой "Сделано". Для примера добавил за 7й месяц результат выполнения, сделано статикой. Необходимо сделать, к примеру, за 8й месяц на формулах.

Всем благодарен за помощь, т.к. бьюсь с этим уже давно.

Comment: `СЧЕТЕСЛИМН()` собсно... три условия - дата после начала месяца, дата до конца месяца, фамилие равно.

Comment: Не подойдет вроде как. Необходимо автоматически считать по всему столбцу "А", чтобы он сам искал необходимый год и месяц и по условию выдавал количество строк.

Comment: *Необходимо автоматически считать по всему столбцу "А"* Ну так не ставь в свойствах ручной пересчёт - оно и будет считаться автоматически.

Comment: Попробовал так: =COUNTIFS(YEAR(A8:A25); D3; MONTH(A8:A25); N2; B8:B25; "Вася"; C8:C25; "Сделано")
С именем и "сделано" проблем нет, но как быть с датой (год и месяц)? Что я не правильно указал?

Comment: Я же русским по белому написал - после начала, до конца... всю дату как есть... а ты выделяешь куски и проверяешь на равно. Наоборот - функциями крути в условии, а не в диапазоне сравнения.

Comment: Имеется ввиду такой вариант =COUNTIFS(A8:A25; ">="&DATE(2018;8;1); A8:A25; "<="&DATE(2018;8;31); B8:B25; "Вася"; C8:C25; "Сделано")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение найдено:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMPRODUCT(1*COUNTIFS(YEAR($A$8:$A$25); $D$3; MONTH($A$8:$A$25); N$2; $B$8:$B$25; $F5; $C$8:$C$25; "Сделано")))
```